# Do we need to use the principal square root to generate multivariate normal samples?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

I am a little confused about a point relating to generating multivariate normal samples. Let's say we want to generate samples from
$$
x \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \Sigma).
$$
Let us further say that we have a matrix square root $B$ such that $BB = \Sigma$. Then we can compute:
$$
z \sim \mathcal{N}(0, I), \\
y = B z.
$$
Then, we have:
$$
\text{Cov}(y, y) = \text{Cov}(Bz, Bz) = B\text{Cov}(z, z)B^\intercal = BB^\intercal.
$$
From this logic, it seems that having a square root is not enough: we need the *principal* square root for which we have $BB^\intercal = BB = B^\intercal B = \Sigma$.

Is my reasoning correct? Do we have to be careful to make sure that the square root of $\Sigma$ is symmetric to be able to use it to sample from a multivariate normal, or am I missing something? Thanks for your help!

Comment: If $\Sigma$ is diagonalizable, $B$ can be determined from the square roots of the Eigenvalues (which are positive). You can choose any sign for these square roots without invalidating the results. So $B$ need not be principal.

Comment: This is helpful, thank you! More generally though, is it true that _any_ square root of $\Sigma$ will do (assuming $\Sigma$ is positive definite), or is there a square root that won't work?